# How to perform setOnCLickListener of ImageView of Scrollable gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am tring to Implement Gallery which contains `TextView` on `ImageView`. When user click any of these I need to call some other Activity.

I tried to call `setonclickListener` on gallery but which always returns result of last item in gallery. If I set `onclicklistener` on Imageview, gallery stops scrolling.

Is there any way to perform click on both and  retrieve the same result and at the same time make gallery scrollable.

Any help is appropriated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code, like your Adapter with CLick Listeners.

Comment: @AndroSelva i add the ImageAdapter class. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this, by setting onItemClickListener on GalleryView, in onItemClick() callback method in this class, there would be an integer parameter respresenting position of item. use this parameter, to get which item has been clicked. But to Use this you need to set Clickable and focusable property of individual item imageview to false.

Comment: i need to pass some data to next activity onClick of ImageView/TextView. Please take a look at ImageAdapter class

Comment: You can return an HashMap in getItem() method, and can use gallery.getAdapter().getItem(position); to get the hashmap in your onItemClick() method. and then can pass these values from the hashmap to another activity.

Comment: thanks. The Gallery working fine now as i want.